# Is there a LINQ way to move data from a flat to a parent / child collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection with question and answer data. Here's a simple example:

```
List<ResultDTO> result1 = new List<ResultDTO> () {
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "abc", AnswerId= 1, AnswerText= "Aab1" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "abc", AnswerId= 2, AnswerText= "Aab2" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "abc", AnswerId= 3, AnswerText= "Aab3" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "def", AnswerId= 4, AnswerText= "Aab4" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "def", AnswerId= 5, AnswerText= "Aab5" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "def", AnswerId= 6, AnswerText= "Aab6" }
};
```

Update

Here's the code that I tried for creating an object as suggested by Martin:

```
var questions = result1
  .GroupBy(
    r => new { r.Id, r.Text },
    (key, results) => new QuestionDTO {
      Id = key.Id,
      Text = key.Text,
      Answers = results
        .Select(r => new AnswerDTO { AnswerId = r.AnswerId, AnswerText = r.AnswerText })
        .ToList()
    }
  )
  .ToList();
```

What I would like to do is to put this into an objective oriented form? I already created
two new classes:

```
    public partial class QuestionDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class AnswerDTO
    {
        public int AnswerId { get; set; }
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResultDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int AnswerId { get; set; }
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: soo, what have you tried? Have you looked at generic methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx) to extract the questions and answers:

```
var questions = result1
  .GroupBy(
    r => new { r.Id, r.Text },
    (key, results) => new Question {
      Id = key.Id,
      Text = key.Text,
      Answers = results
        .Select(r => new Answer { AnswerId = r.AnswerId, AnswerText = r.AnswerText })
        .ToList()
    }
  )
  .ToList();
```

The `Question.Answer` property will be `null` because you have not provided any values for this property.

Here is the result:

```
Id | Text | Answers
---+------+----------------------
1  | abc  | AnswerId | AnswerText
   |      | ---------+-----------
   |      | 1        | Aab1
   |      | 2        | Aab2
   |      | 3        | Aab3
   |      | ---------+-----------
---+------+----------------------
2  | def  | AnswerId | AnswerText
   |      | ---------+-----------
   |      | 4        | Aab4
   |      | 5        | Aab5
   |      | 6        | Aab6
   |      | ---------+-----------
---+------+----------------------
```

Comment: Martin - Thanks very much.  The Answer was actually my mistake. I simplified the question class to focus on the problem and should have removed it. I will try out your suggestion. Looks perfect but will try it out and let you know if I have any questions.  Not time to start typing :-)

Comment: I tried your code (made a few small changes to my initialisation)  but I am getting a couple of errors mentioning about Lambda type. Can you let me know if you have any ideas. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/98607/martin-liversage - here are the errors I am seeing:

Error 2 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<AnonymousType#1>' because it is not a delegate type

Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WebRole.Controllers.UserTestQuestionController.AnswerDTO>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Entities.Models.Core.Answer>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Fixed the problem. It was my bad typing. Will accept the answer. Thanks for your great solution !